# Using the Directory Package and formatting the output

Tags: bibtex, output

Right now, I am trying to use the directory package to manipulate a massive list of addresses. I like it about 90%, but the other 10% is something I am not skilled in changing.

I would like to change the way the directory file is outputting its contents.

for example, the default values I have set for the directory are:

```
\pagestyle{headings}
\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
{\newpage\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

\renewcommand{\Dirheader}[1]
{\item\hspace{-\dirindent}\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

And it outputs something like so:

```
J

Jack Johnson and Kathy
  Street
  City State Zip
  email@yada.com (monospace font)
  mobile: 888.888.888 (Jack)
  mobile: 666.666.666 (Kathy)
```

However, I would like to see the following:

```
J

Johnson, Jack and Kathy
  Street...
  City State Zip
  Jack: email@yada.com (but not in monospace font)
  Jack: 888.888.888
  Kathy: 666.666.666
```

Is this even possible? I'm not skilled with .bst files or the like, and I'm quite a novice all around. Am I biting too much off here?

EDIT: I would also like to be able to avoid a `J` starting the listing to be widowed at the bottom of a page.

Here's a minimal working example:

```
@person{j.k.johnson,
    name = "Johnson, Jack and Kathy",

    p.street = "1234 Sesame Street",
    p.city = "City",
    p.state = "State",
    p.zip = "12345",

    p.email = "email@yada.com",
    p.cellular = "888.888.888 (Jack)",
    r.cellular = "666.666.666 (Kathy)",
}
```

Comment: According to the manual, find the line in `address.bst` that reads: `s nameptr "{ff }{vv }{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ ’t :=` and change it to `s nameptr "{vv }{ll}{ f.}{, jj}" format.name$ ’t :=`. This will put the last name before the first name. I'd need to look in more detail to see how the comma placement works.... Note that a complete but minimal example that people could work off of would be quite helpful. Most, I'd wager, do not have this sort of database already.

Comment: @jon This is true. I'll run that at the least. I was hoping that I didn't have to change the `.bst` file.